# Macro to format y- axis in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-charts, vba

I've written some code to create a second y-axis in a chart. I recorded a macro when I formated the second y-axis and the code looks great. However, it doesn't work when I try to run it from the VBA code..
I've tried the Format Painter (the first y-axis), which would be optimal if it worked, and also by formating the second y-axis "by hand"

This is what I have (and it's doesn't work..)
Formating the second y-axis to Calibri ("by hand"):
`ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).Select
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "+mj-lt"      'This line doesn't work...
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14`

Error code: Method TextFrame2 of Object 'ChartFormat' failed

Using Format Painter:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
Selection.Format.PickUp    'This line doesn't work...
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).Select
```

Error code: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Does anyone know why none of the methods work or if there's a work around?

Comment: You should never (or at least always try to avoid) to use `select`. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Comment: You can use `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats` to do the "Format Painter". But you need to do a `.copy` of something before.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Niclas. However, I don't think the copy paste method is possible when it comes to the y-axis in the chart..

Answer (score 2):

I found a work around by using:

```
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).TickLabels.Font
   .Name = "Calibri"
   .Size = 16
End with
```

I haven't been able to solve the issue with Format Painter though...

Comment: Your solution solved my axis font coloring problem. Based on your post, I ended up with 
    
    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).TickLabels.Font
         .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With