# Generated VBA code for changing the transparency of font for axes is not working?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chart whose axis font I am trying to make transparent. When I use record macro it produces the following code:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("N3").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.349999994
        .Transparency = 0.6000000238
        .Solid
    End With
End Sub
```

But `Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill` throws the error : Method 'TextFrame2' of object 'ChartFormat' failed.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having isn't new. I could find a [post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/format-axis-font-in-vba/2fe979b0-1daa-415d-a550-c9e2c9d29fab) from 2011 on answers.microsoft.com that has the same error message regarding `TextFrame2` or more recently [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405737/macro-to-format-y-axis-in-excel?noredirect=1&lq=1) on Stack Overflow.

The answer that they received was to replace

```vb
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
```

with

```vb
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font
```

The issue is that it only has access to a limited set of properties (which doesn't include transparency):

[image]

**Workaround**

You could always format one chart manually once and then export that chart to a chart template (.crtx file)

[image]

Then, you can simply use code like this to apply the formatting:

```vb
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ApplyChartTemplate "C:\...\ChartTemplate.crtx"
```

Comment: Will this template thing work across all the chart types? I have some line charts, area charts, bar charts, and some complicated mixture of many kinds.

Comment: @user13892 I haven't tested this solution with different chart types, but my guess is that you'll probably need a different template for different chart types.